# Should I use polymer in my chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, polymer, web-component

I have been debating whether using polymer in my chrome extension is worth while.

**Here is the scoop.**  (or should I say scope, haha bad programmer jokes)
My extension relies heavily on web components which have been available natively in chrome since the [release of chrome 36](http://browsernative.com/web-components-support-chrome-316/)

Now, if the browser [statistics listed here](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_chrome.asp) are correct, then logically, there isn't much of a reason to polyfill web components since only a small percentage of chrome users use versions earlier than 36 (and lets face it, chances are they aren't using extensions).

What do you guys think? Are there any other reasons using polymer in this case which I fail to see?

Comment: Hm. I wonder if [this bug/limitation](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=390807) affects you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Xan. Here is another interesting and related resource https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=390807. That being said, If polymer polyfills using ``registerElement`` than it in no way solves my conundrum. I suppose, given this new information - Do you see an advantage to using polymer vs native web components?